# Moving Wordpress from Http To https

Tags: php, wordpress, ssl, https, aws-certificate-manager

I have recently moved my WordPress website from HTTP to HTTPS.

But when i load my webpage with HTTPS the stylesheets doesn't load due to mixed contents . what are the changes i need to do to get it work.

I am using AWS Certificate manager with ELB .

I followed this [tutorial](https://designmodo.com/wordpress-https/)  and now my admin panel is not loading as well with an error of ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Please Assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure all of your CSS links are called with HTTPS. Check your console, it will tell you which url are problematic.
2. Make sure all of the links in your .css files are in HTTPS too, or relative path (background-image urls, fonts urls etc.)
3. Try to use [this Wordpress plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/), it will fix all of yours links.

Comment: can you also help me with https in laravel ?